# How to run msg.exe after opening a shell using cmd.exe

Tags: vb.net

I want to send messages withing a windows 7 LAN using VB.NET code. The problem is that the msg.exe executes commands in admin mode only. Here is the code.

Shell("cmd.exe /k runas /user:farook-pc\administrator msg.exe") 'Here i'm prompted for a password.

Shell("cmd.exe /k msg.exe", 1)

I use the /k switch to see what's going on in the shell. /c is the silent switch. I do not wish to use runas neither do I wish to change privilages in msg.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate launching other apps and trying to control them like that.  If possible, I would recommend trying to mimic the functionality of msg.exe, yourself, programatically.  From doing a few quick google searches, I found that the API function that msg.exe uses is apparently `WTSSendMessage` in Wtsapi32.dll.  Here's the MSDN article on that function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383842(v=vs.85).aspx

And here's a link that shows how to invoke that API function from .NET:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32/wtssendmessage.html

I've never used it before, or even heard of it before, so, unfortunately, I can't help you beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to start the VB.NET application automatically in admin mode.
That can be changed in the project-settings.

After that you can open msg.exe with the following command:

Shell("msg.exe")

Comment: I have changed the app.manifest file to 'requireAdministrator' but I still get the same error message. ‘msg.exe’ is not recoganized as an internal or external command… It runs well when I open a shell from within windows. VS2010 prompts me to open application in Admin mode. I shall follow Steves' links at home at night, there is a lot of reading to do.